# Jest | Mocking a JavaScript created & injected stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom

I've successfully created and injected my stylesheet using JavaScript and I have no issues with the functionality but my tests are now not passing because I get this error
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'parentStyleSheet' of undefined` .

When I run my tests and `console.log(stylesheet)`, indeed it returns as `null`.

I can't even get into the first line of my tests because I get this error thrown at me right at the start.
If I comment out my `insertRule()`, the tests pass.

How can I mock this stylesheet so I can have my tests passing once again?

My function to create a stylesheet:

```
const createStyleSheet = () => {
  this.createdStyleSheet = (function () {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.title = 'carousel';
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return style.sheet;
  }());
};

createStyleSheet();

this.createdStyleSheet.insertRule(---stuff inside here---);
```

Answer (score 3):

I did this to mock insertRule. If you just want to stop it from failing due to undefined this will work. If you actually need the styles added for future tests then you may need to modify this. I only returned 0 to stop my typescript from complaining

```
window.CSSStyleSheet.prototype.insertRule = function (rule, index) {
    const styleElement = document.createElement("style");
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(rule);
    styleElement.appendChild(textNode);
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
    return 0;
};
```

Use this link to see where you need to place your mock function
https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom